# Recommendation Letter from a non Phd faculty member - URGENT!

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter

I am applying for MS/PhD in Petroleum Engineering. My dilemma is that my academic project is under a non-PhD faculty member. She is currently undergoing PhD. Would it be wise to take LOR from her? I am thinking of applying to MS because my LOR's wont be strong enough for PhD in my opinion. Suggestions please

Comment: *I am thinking of applying to MS because my LOR's wont be strong enough for MS in my opinion*. Do you mean you are not applying for PhD instead of MS?

Comment: If it was so extremely urgent, you would have read the information that already exists, instead of waiting for people to write brand-new answers: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49865/8705 http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49322/8705 http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/58323/8705

Answer (score 2):

If you've been working on research with her, then it should be fine. It's akin to asking a boss in industry to write a LoR for you if you were applying for an MS/PhD after several years in industry.

Additionally, most programs ask for at least 2 LoRs, so just make sure the second one is from a PhD-holding faculty member.

Comment: Thanx  a lot, 
Would it work even if I am applying for a PhD program?

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't :-)

Comment: I got into a PhD program with three industry LoR's. At most one of the writers had a PhD.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to graduate school applications the fact that your reccomendation is from a faculty member is orders of magnitude more important than their credentials. (unless they are a undisputed leader in a field, then credentials might matter, but not negatively.)